# ERROR: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, jsonreader

I am getting following error while opening android studio existing project first time **ERROR: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $**

I am getting this error in android 3.3.1

My Project Build File

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App Grade module file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11"
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        shrinkResources true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "DPandStatus_CAD-${variant.name}-vc-${variant.versionCode}-vn-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
//    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.1.0'
}
```

Thank you in advance.. Please help me out... i am stuck from last week

Comment: This error comes when the response from server is not in proper json format so please check the server response.

Comment: Okay. Zoe I will take of this.

Comment: @KarishmaPatel But this error coming while i build project.. Not while execution on device

Comment: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();

Comment: @KarishmaPatel , As I show my app gradle file dependencies. I did not use retrofit. do you have any other idea for this error solution?

Comment: I did not found solution, Create new project and copy paste the source code